# I wanna automatically input now date to a cell when I input a specific value on another cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Apps Script. Simply speaking, I just want to know how to get a value of the specific cell with using Google Apps Script. To make this function, I used the following code.

```
var headers2 = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol2 = headers2[0].indexOf("date") + 1;
var orderCol2 = headers2[0].indexOf("input") + 1;
```

In my opinion, the problem of this code is what it does not distinguish a value that I want, of "input" column.

Comment: You'd use onEdit trigger and event objects. Search for timestamp scripts for a example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This will also handle pastes.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var headers=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Date") + 1;
  var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("Input") + 1;
  if(e.range.columnStart==orderCol) {
    for(var i=0;i<e.range.getHeight();i++) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart + i,dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
  }
}
```